# show image handler with resize

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

before now, i save 2 size of image in database, real size and thumbnail, then show each of them when i need.

in ashx handler i set which type i need, here is my code:

```
            string field = context.Request.QueryString["field"];
            string table = context.Request.QueryString["table"];
            string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];

            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            myConnection.Open();

            string sql = "";
            sql = "Select " + field + ", pictureType from " + table + " where id=@imageId";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imageId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            cmd.Prepare();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();

            context.Response.ContentType = dr["pictureType"].ToString();
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr[field]);
            dr.Close();
            myConnection.Close();
```

and i use this way:

```
<img src="handlers/ShowPic.ashx?table=tblEnBackGrounds&field=image&id=1" alt="s" />
```

but now i decide to save just real size image, then in ashx file re size and show proper type(here real or thumbnail).

now i need first to now is it good or not? second i don't have any idea how to re size binary data before show in ashx handler

Answer (score 0):

Use the great Image Resize lib http://imageresizing.net/.

You need to resize images proportionally and keep their aspect ratio. Using the Image resize lib, something like this could be the function to do the job:

```
public static byte[] resizeProportionaly(byte[] imageFile, int pWidth, int pHeight, string crop = "&crop=auto")
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageFile);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ResizeSettings resizeCropSettings = new ResizeSettings(string.Format("bgcolor=FFFFFF&width={0}&height={1}&format=jpg" + crop, pWidth, pHeight));
        Image originalImage = Image.FromStream(stream, true, false);


        Image resizedImage = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(originalImage, resizeCropSettings);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        resizedImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

and in your handler something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    // some init code...take care of your query strings here etc.

    string cropString = "x1,y1,x2,y2"; // if you need croping? 
    // change height and width based on your picture type
    int outWidth = 640; // whatever you need here
    int outHeight = 480;

    System.Data.DataRow data = GetDBPhotoRecord(photoId);
    byte[] photoStream = (byte[])data[mxmPhotos.Photo]; 
    // if you dont need cropping just remove the last cropString parameter
    byte[] outStream = resizeProportionaly(photoStream, outWidth, outHeight, cropString);

    // ...

    context.Response.Buffer = true;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7));
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(outStream);
}
```

Comment: what ResizeSettings and ImageBuilder in your code? is this consider picture aspect?

Comment: first download the library http://imageresizing.net/.  and the use in your project "using ImageResizer";

Comment: yes (late but i got what it is!), is free edition enough? is there any other way to not use external library? i prefer use my own code!

Comment: free edition is fully sufficient. You can write your own function to resize the image proportionally. Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191424/Resizing-an-Image-On-The-Fly-using-NET